# Collection contains object but cannot remove it

Tags: java, collections

I have a class that holds several collections and I'm having problems removing some of the objects from one of the collections.  If I call collection.contains(object) it returns true then on the next line I call collection.remove(object) and the object doesn't get removed.

This is the original code that didn't work.  All of the collections are SortedSets.  What confused me here was that the male collection is populated directly from the people collection, but when you try to remove the male objects from the people collections not all of them will be removed.

```
    for(Person person : peopleBin.getPeople())
    {
        if(person.isMale())
        {
            peopleBin.getMen().add(person);
        }
    }
    peopleBin.getPeople().removeAll(peopleBin.getMen());
```

Person has an equals method like this

```
public boolean equals( Object obj ) 
{
    if ( obj == null )
        return false;
    if ( !(obj instanceof Person) )
        return false;
    Person that = (Person)obj;
    return
        that.age == age &&
        that.id == id &&
        that.someCount == someCount ;
}
```

Now when I replaced the first snippet's removeAll line with this I get strange behavior.

```
    for(Person person: personBin.getMen())
    {
        if(personBin.getPeople().contains(person)) 
            personBin.getPeople().remove(person);
    }
```

if(personBin.getPeople().contains(person))  always returns true, but personBin.getPeople().remove(person) does not always remove.  Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.

I have changed all of the class names and field names to be generic to post in a public forum.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: here is the compareTo impl

```
    public int compareTo (Object o)
{
    if ( ! ( o instanceof Person) ) 
    {
        throw new ClassCastException();
    }

    Person that = (Person)o;

    int comparison = 0;

    return 
        ( (comparison = this.age () - that.age ()) != 0 ? comparison :
        ( (comparison = this.id - that.id) != 0 ? comparison :
        ( (comparison = this.someCount - that.someCount ))));
}
```

edit: here is the hashCode impl

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 31;
    result = 61*result + age;
    result = 61*result + id;
    result = 61*result + someCount;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the comparator implementation?  Or `compareTo`, if you're just using the natural ordering?

Comment: Switch the code in your bottom example to `if(peopleBin.getPeople().remove(person)) { println("Removed" +person); } else { println("Didn't remove" + person); }`, and see if you can identify any patterns.

Comment: What did the `removeAll` return? A `true` or `false` ?

Comment: do you get any error messages? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: and you may need a hashCode method also to sit alongside equals

Comment: Can we see the class declaration?  That is, the line `public class Person implements ...`  (I'm suspicious of your generics.)

Comment: public class Person implements Comparable

Comment: Hrrrmkay.  I'm suspicious that maybe you should be using generics, but you may not be on Java 5. Also, just to check: are `age`, `id`, and `someCount` final?  Or at least, are they all left unmodified during all of these operations?

Comment: ColinD - There are no error messages returned and i have been debugging it.
Ravinder - removeAll returns true but does not remove all of the objects, it leaves 1 in there.
LouisWasserman - We are on Java 6 but this class was written back in Java 3.  Age, id and someCount are not final but they are also not modified between the time the are added to the men collection and removed from the people colletion.

Comment: If I were to load of the people collection, modify some of the fields in some of the objects of people, then run my first snippet would it not remove the objects that were modified. In other words, does modifying a the elements of a collection after they were loaded in the collection make them not removable?

Comment: Yes, it does -- specifically, it corrupts the whole collection, more or less unrecoverably.  That's why you should only put unmodifiable objects into a `Set`.  If I were you, I'd try seeing if the bug still occurs with different `Collection` implementations.  The code you've provided looks more or less good so far, but by far the most common reasons for bugs like this are modifying the objects, bad comparators/hash code implementations, or a bad equals implementation.

Comment: hallelujah! @LouisWasserman you are my hero.  I have been banging my head on my desk for hours trying to figure out what is going on.  I never new this about collections and I will be very weary of this in the future, thank you!

Comment: If you only change data which does not affect the result of hashCode, equals or compareTo (depending on your choice of Set), you'll be fine. Even if your set breaks you can add all entries to a new set, it will be usable as java will sort the set as they are added (addAll will not work because it's too "smart").

Comment: To be clear, it's fine in `List`, just not in `Set` or as a `Map` key, as specified in the `Set` javadoc: "Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element."

Answer (score 0):

To remove an item from a colelction , the best way is to use an Iterator to avoid any problem :

replace you loop by this, and try again :

```
for(Iterator<Person> iterator =  personBin.getMen().iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            Person person = iterator.next();
            if(personBin.getPeople().contains(person)){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```